# Exception in drools rules syntax

Tags: java, drools

I am trying to write drool rules using two different POJO class as below.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        dbRules = new DbRules(i, "Rule Name - " + i, "  $mdmContractHeader : MdmContractHeader();  $contractHeader1 : ContractHeader (supplierName==$mdmContractHeader.supplierName); "
                + " &&  contractHeader:ContractHeader(supplierId >= 100)",
                "System.out.print(\"Test, Drools rule - " + i
                        + ".! \"); System.out.println(contractHeader.getSupplierName());");
        list.add(dbRules);
    }
```

After execution, I am facing below exception. It looks like I am getting error with pojo class declaration.

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get KieModule, Errors Existed: Error Messages:
      Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/Sample.drl, line=1, column=0
    text=[ERR 102] Line 1:306 mismatched input '$contractHeader1' in rule "Rule Name - 0"]
        Message [id=2, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/Sample.drl, line=1, column=0
      text=[ERR 102] Line 1:723 mismatched input '$contractHeader1' in rule "Rule Name - 1"]
      Message [id=3, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/Sample.drl, line=1, column=0
     text=[ERR 102] Line 1:1140 mismatched input '$contractHeader1' in rule "Rule Name - 2"]
     Message [id=4, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/Sample.drl, line=1, column=0
    text=[ERR 102] Line 1:1557 mismatched input '$contractHeader1' in rule "Rule Name - 3"]
    Message [id=5, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/Sample.drl, line=1, column=0
    text=[ERR 102] Line 1:1974 mismatched input '$contractHeader1' in rule "Rule Name - 4"]
     Message [id=6, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/Sample.drl, line=0, column=0
      text=Parser returned a null Package]
  ---
  Warning Messages:
 ---
 Info Messages:

at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getKieModule(KieBuilderImpl.java:467)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.getKieModule(KieBuilderImpl.java:453)
at com.sample.StringDroolsMdm.executeRules(StringDroolsMdm.java:118)
at com.sample.StringDroolsMdm.main(StringDroolsMdm.java:70)
```

I have updated the content in StringBuffer as below but still getting the same exception.

```
 import com.model.ContractHeader; 
 import com.model.MdmContractHeader; 
 import static com.service.SupplierService.isRuleAppliesToSupplier;  
 rule "Rule Name - 0" 
  when 
 cHeader:ContractHeader() 
 eval(isRuleAppliesToSupplier((cHeader.getSupplierName()) , 0 )) && 
 ( 
 $mdmContractHeader:MdmContractHeader($s : supplierName) 
 $myContractHeader:ContractHeader(supplierName == $s) 
  contractHeader:ContractHeader(supplierId >= 100)  
 ) 
  then 
 System.out.print("Test, Drools rule - 0.! "); System.out.println(contractHeader.getSupplierName()); 
 end;
```

And exception is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get KieModule, Errors Existed: Error Messages:
Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/Sample.drl, line=10, column=0
   text=[ERR 102] Line 10:1 mismatched input '$myContractHeader' in rule "Rule Name - 0"]
Message [id=2, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/Sample.drl, line=0, column=0
   text=Parser returned a null Package]
---
```

Comment: Could you share how the final DRL looks like?

Comment: I am trying to create rule with string buffer in which lhs and rhs extracted from db. In above code, DbRules is pojo class which have rulename,lhs and rhs. I am facing the syntax issue while generating lhs part. In Lhs part, I am trying to create object of two pojo class and comparing the supplier name data.

Comment: StringBuffer ruleBuffer = new StringBuffer();
  ruleBuffer.append("import com.model.ContractHeader; import com.model.MdmContractHeader; import static com.service.SupplierService.isRuleAppliesToSupplier;  ");
  for(DbRules rule : dbRuleList) {
   ruleBuffer.append(" rule \""+rule.getRuleName()+"\" when cHeader:ContractHeader(); eval( isRuleAppliesToSupplier(  (cHeader.getSupplierName()) , "+rule.getRuleId()+" )) && ("+rule.getLhs()+") then "+rule.getRhs()+" end; ");
  }

Comment: Please provide the content of your StringBuffer

Comment: @EstebanAliverti  I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that you can do to make your rules look better:

- Remove the `;` after the first pattern and after the `end` keyword.
- Add a `\n` after the name of the rule and after the `when` and `then` keywords.
- Add a `\n` after each of your patterns.
- Do not use unnecessary `&&` between patterns.

After these changes, your rules should look something like this:

```
rule "Rule Name - 0" 
when 
  cHeader:ContractHeader() 
  eval(isRuleAppliesToSupplier((cHeader.getSupplierName()) , 0 )) && 
  (  
    $mdmContractHeader : MdmContractHeader( $s : supplierName )  
    $contractHeader1 : ContractHeader ( supplierName == $s ) 
    contractHeader: ContractHeader(supplierId >= 100)
  ) 
then 
  System.out.print("Test, Drools rule - 0.! "); System.out.println(contractHeader.getSupplierName()); 
end;
```

My guess is that the error is caused because of the lack of a `\n` after the `MdmContractHeader()` pattern.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I have updated the rule(in Question) but still getting the same error.

Comment: Could you try by removing the `&&` after your `eval` and the parenthesis that are wrapping the following patterns? If that works, try to replace the `&&` with the `AND` keyword.